Check auth status of users in a Vue.js Frontend with an HTTPOnly JWT Token in ASP.NET Web API
I'm building a web application with an ASP.NET Web API backend and a Vue.js frontend. I've implemented JWT authentication and am storing the access token in an HTTPOnly cookie for security reasons. However, I'm facing a challenge in checking users auth status on the frontend.
Since the token is HTTPOnly, it's inaccessible from JavaScript, including Vue.js. This means I can't directly check if a user is authenticated on the frontend.
My question is how can I effectively check users auth status on the Vue.js frontend while maintaining the security of the HTTPOnly JWT token? Are there any recommended strategies or patterns to achieve this?

You can have a dedicated endpoint for checking auth status. If user info fetching is lightweight or you use OPTIONS method, you can use it, for instance. You can ping it occasionally but there may be no need for that. As long as a user successfully logged in, consider them logged in. When you receive 401/403 from another api call, you need to make another request to that endpoint to make sure it's authentication and not authorization problem, then change client side status to guest. Or skip the extra req if there's clear distinction between 401 and 403 in your api

The question is too broad for SO, try https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ if you still have unsolved questions

you can create a authorized endpoint in web api like GetAuthStatus and validate it on client side on route change. it recommended to keep the token in HttpOnly cookie.
Something like this
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetAuthStatus()
{
     return Ok(new { isAuthenticated = true, userName = User.Identity.Name 
     });
}

